# Implicit derivative of equation with variable on both sides

Tags: calculus

I'm a bit confused on how to implicitly solve this derivative. Can anyone provide some insight? The equation is:
$$Y(n)=\left(a + bY(n)^x\right)^n$$

Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: What a mess. :D

Comment: @Tavish yeah, anyway I can make this easier to get a response? Maybe I'll try to simplify it

Comment: Differentiation in this manner is fine. This is what you would call implicit differentiation.

Comment: Agree @Tavish (and just made an easier example) , I'm a bit lost because it seems like you could replace $Y'$ infinite times. Also, i'm not sure how to think of the sign of this derivative because the derivative itself appears on both sides.

Comment: You do not have to recursively replace $Y’$. Think of it like a variable that you aim to isolate to one side. Can you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity I’ll write $Y(n)$ as $Y$ and $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial n}$ as $Y’$. We have

$$Y=(a+bY^x)^n$$
$$\frac{1}{Y} Y’= (n \log(a+bY^x))’$$
$$=\left[ n \times \frac{1}{a+bY^x} \times bxY^{x-1}\times Y’\right] + \log(a+bY^x)$$
Collecting terms containing $Y’$ to the left,
$$Y’ \bigg(\frac 1Y - \frac{nbxY^{x-1}}{a+bY^x} \bigg) = \log(a+bY^x)$$
$$ Y’ \bigg( \frac{a+bY^x - nbxY^x}{Y(a+bY^x)} \bigg) = \log(a+bY^x)$$
$$\implies Y’=\frac{Y(a+bY^x)\log(a+bY^x)}{a+ bY^x(1-nx)}$$

Comment: Thanks, I had clearly made a mistake from the beginning by wrongly derivating the exponential function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $Y(n) > 0$ applying $\ln$ to both sides

$$
\ln(Y(n))-n\ln\left(a+b Y(n)^x\right)=0
$$

and differentiating regarding $n$

$$
-\frac{b n x Y(n)^{x-1} Y'(n)}{a+b y(n)^x}-\ln \left(a+b Y(n)^x\right)+\frac{Y'(n)}{Y(n)}=0
$$

and solving for $Y(n)$ we get

$$
Y'(n) = \frac{Y(n) \left(a+b Y(n)^x\right) \ln \left(a+b Y(n)^x\right)}{a+(b-b n x) Y(n)^x}
$$